# pandas element wise conditional return index

Tags: pandas

I want to find  abnormal values and replace them with corresponding day of next week.

```
year    week    day  v1   v2
2001    1         1  46   9999
2001    1         2  60   9335
2001    1         3 9999  9318
2001    1         4  47   9999
2001    1         5  57   9373
2001    1         6  9999 9384
2001    1         7  72   9444
2001    2         1  75    73
2001    2         2  74    63
2001    2         3  79    377
2001    2         4  70    361
2001    2         5  75    73
2001    2         6  77    64
2001    2         7  76    57
```

I could carry out column by column,code as follows:

```
index_row=df[df['v1']==9999].index
for i in index_row:
    df['v1'][i]=df['v1'][i+7]   # i+7 is the index of next week
```

How to element-wise the whole dataframe? Such as `pd.applymap`.
How get the columns number(name) and row number base on conditional seiving values?

The target df I want as follows:
( `*` indicated modified values and the next week values)

```
year    week    day  v1   v2
2001    1         1  46   *73
2001    1         2  60   9335
2001    1         3  *79   9318
2001    1         4  47   *361
2001    1         5  57    9373
2001    1         6  *77   9384
2001    1         7  72    9444
2001    2         1  75    *73
2001    2         2  74    63
2001    2         3  *79   377
2001    2         4  70    *361
2001    2         5  75    73
2001    2         6  *77   64
2001    2         7  76    57
```

Comment: I'm done editing.  That's a good answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create `d1` with `set_index` on columns `['year', 'week', 'day']`
create `d2` with same index as `d1` except, subtract `1` from `week`
`mask` with `other`

```
cols = ['year', 'week', 'day']
d1 = df.set_index(cols)
d2 = df.assign(week=df.week - 1).set_index(cols)
d1.mask(d1.eq(9999), d2).reset_index()

    year  week  day  v1    v2
0   2001     1    1  46    73
1   2001     1    2  60  9335
2   2001     1    3  79  9318
3   2001     1    4  47   361
4   2001     1    5  57  9373
5   2001     1    6  77  9384
6   2001     1    7  72  9444
7   2001     2    1  75    73
8   2001     2    2  74    63
9   2001     2    3  79   377
10  2001     2    4  70   361
11  2001     2    5  75    73
12  2001     2    6  77    64
13  2001     2    7  76    57
```

***old answer***

One approach is to setup `d1` with index of `['year', 'week', 'day']` and manipulate that to shift a week.  Then mask it for equal to `9999` and `fillna`

```
d1 = df.set_index(['year', 'week', 'day'])
s1 = d1.unstack(['year', 'day']).shift(-1).stack(['year', 'day']).swaplevel(0, 1)
d1.mask(d1==9999).fillna(s1).reset_index()

    year  week  day    v1      v2
0   2001     1    1  46.0    73.0
1   2001     1    2  60.0  9335.0
2   2001     1    3  79.0  9318.0
3   2001     1    4  47.0   361.0
4   2001     1    5  57.0  9373.0
5   2001     1    6  77.0  9384.0
6   2001     1    7  72.0  9444.0
7   2001     2    1  75.0    73.0
8   2001     2    2  74.0    63.0
9   2001     2    3  79.0   377.0
10  2001     2    4  70.0   361.0
11  2001     2    5  75.0    73.0
12  2001     2    6  77.0    64.0
13  2001     2    7  76.0    57.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can working with [`DatetimeIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html), set value by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)ed rows:

```
a = df['year'].astype(str).add('-').add(df['week'].astype(str))
                          .add('-').add(df['day'].sub(1).astype(str))
#http://strftime.org/
df.index = pd.to_datetime(a, format='%Y-%U-%w')
df2 = df.shift(-1,freq='7D')
df = df.mask(df.eq(9999), df2).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
    year  week  day  v1    v2
0   2001     1    1  46    73
1   2001     1    2  60  9335
2   2001     1    3  79  9318
3   2001     1    4  47   361
4   2001     1    5  57  9373
5   2001     1    6  77  9384
6   2001     1    7  72  9444
7   2001     2    1  75    73
8   2001     2    2  74    63
9   2001     2    3  79   377
10  2001     2    4  70   361
11  2001     2    5  75    73
12  2001     2    6  77    64
13  2001     2    7  76    57
```